# jQuery .lenght attribute doesnt return the correct value

Tags: jquery

Following problem:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1" class="div">Div #1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="div">Div #2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="div">Div #3</div>
    <div id="div4" class="div">Div #4</div>
    <div id="div5" class="div">Div #5</div>
</div>
```

I want to count all the elements inside the container, so i tried this one:

```
$("#container").length;
```

Didnt work, it returns 1 even if there are obviously 5 elements inside. Where is my error? Im unable to find out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: alert($("#container > div").length); mate.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work - you're asking for how many elements there are with an id of `#container`.

To count elements INSIDE the container, try this:

```
$('#container div').length
```

Comment: @YUNOWORK awesome! feel free to mark this as the answer if you feel it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

Try using this,

```
$("#container div").length;
```

I just used a `descendant` selector above, If you want to select only the `children` inside that particular div, Then you should change your selector like this `$("#container > div")`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XDtM7/)

Answer (score 2):

`.length` returns length of selector.

Your selector is `#container` so it returns 1.

If you want length of children of `#container`, then write

```
$("#container .div").length;
```

Comment: As I am not a javascript pro, so just for my curiosity, what is the difference between `$("#container .div").length;` and `$("#container div").length;`?? - @Hiral

Comment: `$("#container .div").length` will return number elements having class `div` under `#container` and `$("#container div").length` will return number `div` elements under `#container`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,First you select appropriate element to detect length

container returns 1

container div returns 5

```
$("#container div").length;
```